# Helper not found when creating an adminHtml module

Tags: xml, magento

I have started to follow [this Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited) tutorial on creating a AdminHtml section within a module that I have created.

On viewing this tutorial I can see that the Admin facility is being done as a seperate module, is this the recommended way of doing things, or is it done this way for simplicity sake? I am adding my adminhtml into my module, should I do it separately?

I am getting an error

```
Mage_Ps_Prefcentre_Helper_Data' not found in  ... on line 546
```

I have added my Helper_Data file, and in adminHtml.xml i have added the following code

```
<config>
<menu>
    <prefcentre translate="title" module="ps_prefcentre">
        <title>Prefcentre</title>
        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        <children>
            <example>
                <title>Example</title>
                <action>adminhtml/admin</action>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            </example>
        </children>
    </prefcentre>
</menu>
</config>
```

Ive also added the necessary data into the config.xml file

```
 <global>
  .........
    <helpers>
        <prefcentre>
            <class>Ps_Prefcentre_Helper</class>
        </prefcentre>
    </helpers>
  .........
</global>
```

the file structure is

- Ps
- - Prefcentre
- - - Helper
- - - - Data.php
- - - Controllers
- - - - AdminController.php
- - - etc
- - - - adminHtml.xml

Why am I getting the cant find helper data?

Comment: In system.xml try with `module="prefcentre"` same name as your node from config.xml > global > helpers

Comment: Thank you, that worked, but why? I thought module= was directing magento to the moduleName followed by the Namespace. Is magento just searching for a namespace when i'm dealing with admin modules? and if that is the case, will namespaces of the same name in separate modules cause conflicts?

Comment: The Data.php helper is used for translations by default so the line module="ps_prefcentre"  would translate to Mage::helper('ps_prefcentre'); and Magento doesn't know how to autoload this class since in your config you have `<helpers>
        <prefcentre>`. You have to use the same name in both cases.